# What would be the complexity of the following Program

Tags: java, recursion

This program recursively prints all the possible combinations of the given String
I am confused by the statement inside the for loop which recursively calls itself. Is it implicit n*n where n is the length of the String

```
   public static void getStringCombination(String prefix, String str) {
     System.out.println(prefix);
     for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
     getStringCombination(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(i + 1));
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by complexity? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I mean the runtime complexity.After thinking several times I am still confused whether it is linear or implicit quadratic

Comment: Because the for loop calls the method again which further calls the for loop and so on

Comment: What does your calling method look like? And how many times does the print statement occur when you run it?

Comment: getStringCombination("","ABC") would result in printing A,B,C,AB,AC,ABC

Comment: Can you write a recurrence relation for the complexity?

Comment: Wouldn't `getStringCombination("","ABC")` print A, AB, ABC, AC, B, BC, C? I think that's the expected order because you would recurse down before doing the other loop iterations, but in any case it seems like BC should be in the list somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Although I personally always have trouble with determining such things I would have to say that this is factorial.
The first hint is that you're printing `all the possible combination` which is more or less factorial if I remember my high-school maths correctly.
The second hint is that you're doing a for loop over the whole string in which you do the recursive call, so the first call you'll do N recursive calls, then for the next recursive call you'll do N-1 recursive calls etc.

I must say that after saying this I'm kind of doubting myself and the fact if it actually does print all possible combinations... I'm quite positive it doesn't print combinations that involve the latter characters being in front of the first characters. This might make my statement about it being factorial incorrect, but I can't say I'm sure about this.

**EDIT**

After reading @Ben S.'s answer and testing I'm fairly sure that your example is O(2^n) and my thought that Ben S.'s "fix" is O(n!) however it seems I'm wrong, it's actually higher.
I'm afraid I can't explain why your example is 2^n though, still pondering on it myself.

Answer (score 0):

It should be close to O(n2), however we cannot say this is precise because this is the case of recursion.